# AMPscript if/then/else & variables

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I have some basic AMPscript pulling content in based on value of the `@AccountBalance` attribute in my DE:

```ampscript
%%[IF @AccountBalance >= '2000' THEN]%%
HTML
%%[ELSE THEN]%%
HTML
```

I wasn't getting the results I expected, people with 0 points were getting the right content but people with more than 0 but less than 2000 as their `AccountBalance` were getting the `>= 2000` content.

I was able to play around with the code to get it to work (I thought), by removing the quotes around 2000 so the code read `%%[IF @AccountBalance >= 2000 THEN]%%`. I assumed that the system was looking for `AccountBalance` values of *exactly* 2000. However, while the people under 2000 points were getting the right content, people over were not.

Once I set `@AccountBalance = ACCOUNTBALANCE`, then it all seemed to come together.  But I don't know why.  We use `AccountBalance` and other variables like `@FirstName` in our emails without specifically declaring them, so why was it different this time?

Comment: What's the data type of `AccountBalance` in the send context?

Comment: it's text data type

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I'd suggest:

```ampscript
%%[

set @accountBalance = AttributeValue("accountBalance")
set @accountBalance = "$1,000" /* for testing */

if empty(@accountBalance) then
  set @accountBalance = 0
else
  set @accountBalance = replaceList(@accountBalance,"",",","$"," ")
  set @accountBalance = add(@accountBalance,0)
endif

if @accountBalance > 2000 then 
  output(concat("balance is more than 2000"))
else 
  output(concat("balance is less than or equal to 2000"))
endif

]%%
```

Try it yourself: https://mcsnippets.herokuapp.com/s/NmyrdN38

Answer (score 1):

It depends on if ACCOUNTBALANCE is a number or not. When comparing strings, 3 is greater than 2000 (3 is greater than 2), so 3 >= 2000 is true. However, if you compare numbers, you'll get the values you expect. You should also be able to write:

```
%%[IF FormatNumber(@AccountBalance, "N") >= 2000 THEN]%%
```

Comment: This'll work however, the `formatNumber` will throw a compiler error if you don't pass it a numeric value, e.g. `$2000.`

Comment: @AdamSpriggs I only addressed the likely initial problem given the limited information in the question, and I honestly have about 5 seconds worth of actual MC experience, lol. Your answer was definitely enlightening.